# Is there a way to see sent data when the server is https?

Tags: ssl, tcp, https, tls1.2

I am trying to see data (using tcpdump) which my browser sends to server which is using https protocol
tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/http.log
but application data is encrypted(as it was expected).
I am wondering is there a way to see data before it will be encrypted when the server is https?

EDIT:  Encryption traffic is created by common web browsers like Firefox, Chrome, IE...

Comment: What application is creating the TLS encrypted traffic? A custom application or a web browser? And on which platform. Please edit your question and update the additional information.

Comment: I have edited .

Comment: Common web browsers like Firefox, Chrome, IE... have built in developer tools that allow to monitor network traffic before the TLS protection is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the server, you can set it to permit the null cipher then force your client to use the same. The null cipher is just a fancy way of saying "unencrypted". This should NEVER be deployed, as even having it as an option in the ciphers list is HIGHLY insecure.

You could also add a trusted key to the client, and have the client use a proxy. The communication with the proxy uses the trusted key you created, and can look at the data before sending it on, encrypted with the key of the destination server. This is, effectively, a "Man in the Middle attack," and can be defeated by things like certificate pinning. Some companies use this to track employee computer usage (when used in that way, it's somewhat controversial).

Strictly speaking, both of those are attacks to get around the encryption, not looking at the data before it's encrypted. To see it before it's encrypted, you would, generally, have to modify either the client or server to record what it's sending (or maybe use a debugger), as generally the encryption is done by a library directly linked to the programme.

EDIT: the developer tools in Chrome and Firefox might be what you're looking for: if you click the page on the "network" tab (in chrome, I don't have FF up, but it has almost exactly the same thing) you can see almost all the aspects of the info being sent and received.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Unnaturally I don't control server and can't change any settings there.
For the second point not really sure if it will give the result that I need, my purpose is to see the data which is generated by one web page when I click send button(it sends data using ajax so I don't see how the data it is formatted), so If I use second method which you described, will I be able to see that data?

Comment: If your client is Chrome or Firefox, the developer tools might have what you are looking for. (edited the answer to reflect that)

Comment: Thank, developer tool for Firefox gave me what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) (free trial) on your computer. If the certificate is pinned this will not work bit that is probably not the case for a browser..